# Roku Scene Graph - create new scene

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I'm trying to run a sample app from Roku with their new SceneGraph API but i get stuck at the beginning, when i'm trying to create a new scene. I didn't modified anything.

The error that i received is:

BRIGHTSCRIPT: ERROR: roSGScreen.CreateScene: No such node HomeScene: pkg:/source/main.brs(7)

You can find the sample code here: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/download/attachments/1608528/Simple_Grid_and_Video.zip

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that HomeScene.brs file is included for deployment. If you are using Eclipse plugin, in BrightScript deployment wizard check whether HomeScene.brs file is selected.

Comment: It seems that was something wrong with the plugin update. I reinstall it and now it's working. Thank you for answer!